# Indentify "\r\n.\r\n" in the strings you are sending from client to server

Tags: java

I am sending several messages in my application from client to server one of them is "\r\n.\r\n" how can the server identify this message between others?
I have used equals() method but it did not work:

```
 is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket
                    .getInputStream()));
 String st = is.readLine();
 if(st.equals("\r\n.\r\n"))
     // ........
```

Comment: Are you aware that `"\r\n"` is a line delimeter, meaning that it won't ever show up in the result of `readLine`, let alone twice?

Comment: what you want is that finding the end of complete message from client right?

Comment: <START_MSG>Hi How are You<END_MSG> , why dont u look for tags"<END_MSG>" instead of carriage return

Comment: @Suresh, this looks suspiciously like SMTP or similar protocol. Such protocols usually don't use any start/end tags, otherwise a "." terminator wouldn't be needed.

Comment: @Suresh yes i have written parsers for SMTP mail messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket
                    .getInputStream()));

is.mark(5);
char[] tmp = new char[5];
is.read(tmp, 0, 5);

if(new String(tmp).equals("\r\n.\r\n"))
   // you have that message
else
   is.reset();
```

Comment: That's good if the first "\r\n" weren't "eaten" by the previous call to readLine() or whatever mechanism is used for line reading.

Comment: @Sergey: what previous call to readLine ?? the InputStream is wrapped and then immediately marked for a reset? @Elton: np ;-)

Comment: @Aafron, I mean that "\r\n.\r\n" is used to indicate the end of a message, but the message itself can contain several lines of text. If you read those lines using readLine() before checking for "\r\n.\r\n", then the last call to readLine() will eat up the terminating "\r\n", and then you won't be able to check for "\r\n.\r\n" any more because it becomes ".\r\n" then. It will only work if you really have "\r\n\r\n.\r\n" there or if you don't use readLine() to read the previous lines of the message.

Answer (score 3):

If this is just "." on a separate line like in the SMTP, then you could just use `st.equals(".")`, as readLine() strips EOL characters. But if you need to make sure it's exactly "\r\n.\r\n", and not "\n.\n" for example, then you should probably avoid readLine() and implement line reading by yourself, possibly reading character-by-character.

Comment: Indeed. Good to notice that for readLine both \r\n and \n denote end of line, and that if they need to be distinguished you need to write your own parser.